# Conver datetime format in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a column with value `9/12/2012 00:00:00.000000` in a MySQL table, how do I update the table to make the value like `2012-12-9 00:00:00.000000`.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do would be to convert your text date column to a proper datetime column using `STR_TO_DATE`:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET newDate = STR_TO_DATE(oldDate, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s.%f');
```

Once you have done this, you may *view* your datetime column any way you want:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(newDate, '%Y-%d-%m %H:%i:%s.%f') AS newDateFormatted
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: using `UPDATE yourTable
SET newDate = str_to_date(oldDate, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s.%f');` I get the following error message `Error Code: 1411. Incorrect datetime value: '8/31/2012 00:00:00.000000' for function str_to_date`

Comment: @user231124ns11 I assumed that `9/12/2012` meant 9th December, 2012.  I have updated my answer under the assumption that this means 12th Septemeber, 2012.